# How to change position of buttons. objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, autolayout

The method on stackoverflow to position a button is not working. I'm using

```
self.todayButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.todayButton.frame.origin.y, self.todayButton.frame.size.width, self.todayButton.frame.size.height);
```

I think its an autolayout issue but i'm not sure how to fix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an issue with `Autolayout`. But you can't disable `autolayout` on a specific view in the nib. It has to be disabled on the whole nib. 
Better solution is to use `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` on that button:

```
 [self.todayButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
```

Comment: Hii when i do this, it is giving in log like this:                                          Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints

Comment: Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x8b2a230 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:|-(262)-[UIButton:0x8bd8750]   (Names: '|':UIScrollView:0x8baba30 )>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth splitting this code up so you can see what the new frame looks like:

```
CGRect newFrame = self.todayButton.frame;
NSLog(@"Old: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(newFrame));
newFrame.origin.x = 0;
NSLog(@"New: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(newFrame));
self.todayButton.frame = newFrame;
```

Does the displayed frame look like what you expected?

Comment: Old: {{569, 13}, {73, 44}}
New: {{0, 13}, {73, 44}}   
button stays exactly where it is.

Comment: Well, at least you've ruled that out! I hope Puneet's answer above helps solve the problem. Good luck.